# Алгоритм вычисления лояльности клиента

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, математика, информатика

Требуется рассчитать лояльность клиента в компании.
Критерии лояльного клиента:

- Сотрудничает бесперебойно весь период как пришел первый раз (поле год заключения договора);
- Сотрудничает на постоянной основе но мог пропустить 1 год;
- Или новый клиент который заключил договор в текущем году

Есть массив данных выгруженный из БД:
[image: Массив]

Последнее поле сортировка - это функция row_number которая пронумеровала мне договора у каждого клиента.

Подскажите как можно реализовать данный алгоритм, на sql или Python, может описание просто, ибо не совсем понимаю в части того как обходить все договора у каждого клиента. Интересно было бы посмотреть реализацию на Python, можно с использованием Pandas можно на чистом змее.
Есть предположение, что мне нужно делать двойной цикл for, который будет выбирать ID Клиента и второй, который будет проверять его строки. Спасибо.

Comment: во-первых, из описания непонятно какой результат вы ожидаете получить да и алгоритм не совсем понятен. Во-вторых, никто не будет вбивать данные с картинки, чтобы помочь вам. PS в вашем предыдущем вопросе я вам давал ссылку - советую прочитать ответ по ней...

Comment: `на sql или Python` — хороший такой разброс вариантов. не хуже чем «на русском или на севере».